# EsLint - Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I get error `Unable to resolve path to module 'react-scroll'`

however, I added `react-scroll` to dependencies

[image]

In my file I have  `import { Element } from 'react-scroll';`. I use Eslint. Why I get such error?

Comment: Did you add 'react-scroll' dependency into package.json manually or with package manager? If you did it manually try to reinstall dependencies.

Comment: @staxval Yeah, remove the `node_modules` folder and all and reinstall

Comment: Why? What is the difference?